# Bootstrap 4 branding element pushing navbar to a new line

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, nav

[I want to have a fixed top navbar like this with (Because its one list item I dont need the hamburger toggleable feature)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAKr2.jpg)

However the navbar brand element pushed the navigation to a new row. I tried the pull-right class and a justify-content-end but neighter of them worked.

[It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rziue.jpg)

My code so far is like this. Thank you for your help!

```css
body{
  padding-top: 130px;
}

.navbar{
 padding-top: 1rem;
 padding-bottom: 2rem;
 height: 130px;
}

.bg-faded{
 background-color: white;
}

.navbar-brand{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2.20rem;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 font-weight: 900;
}


.nav-item a{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.jumbotron{
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

#week1{
     background-image: url('../img/week1.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <title>52 Weeks of Portrait</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900|Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">52 Weeks of Portrait</a>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About + Rules</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="week1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-3">Week One</h1>
      <p class="lead"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
 
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i understand right, you want such effect? https://jsfiddle.net/06fv6ona/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your brand to div with class 'navbar-header' and use:

```
float:left
```

and

```
float:right
```

to .navbar-nav